# Query on callback function receiving KeyBoardEvent instance

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, keyboard-events, eventhandler

In the below code,

```
<form action="#" id="sampForm">
      <input id='charInput' type='text'>
      <p id="keyData">Key Data Here</p>
</form><br>

<script>
     document.getElementById('charInput').onkeypress = f;


     function f(event) {
         var char = getChar(event || window.event)
         if (!char) return false; // Special Key pressed
         document.getElementById('keyData').innerHTML = char + " was pressed";
         return true;
     }

     function getChar(event) {
         // event.which returns the key pressed
         if (event.which == null) {
           // Return the char if not a special character
           return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); // IE
         } else if (event.which!=0 && event.charCode!=0) {
             return String.fromCharCode(event.which);   // Other Browsers
         } else {
            return null; // Special Key pressed
         }
     }

</script>
```

---

Before assigning a callback function `f`, `onkeypress` is `null`

> `>  var obj = document.getElementById('charInput');`
>
> ```
>    undefined
> ```
>
> `>  obj.onkeypress`
>
> ```
>    null
> ```
>
> `>  Object.prototype.toString.call(document.getElementById('charInput'));`
>
> ```
>      [object HTMLInputElement]
> ```

1)

For any `HTMLInputElement` type instance, How do I know that property `onkeypress` is suppose to have a value which is a callback function `f` with a signature having single parameter(`event`) receiving `KeyBoardEvent` object and that `f` returns `true`? Do we have any w3c spec reference? How many arguments can be passed to callback function `f`?

2)

In general, for any `HTMLInputElement` type instance, How did I know that properties like `onfocus`, `onblur`, `onselect` has to have a value, which is a callback function with signature like function  `f`?

Comment: Browsers which fallows the W3C standard always pass the event object as the first parameter to the assigned handler. That implies also that if you do not assign a handler to the specific event property of the element it contains `null`. What's the exact context where you find ambiguity about that?

Comment: @VincentDamiani How do I know, if the callback function `f` is supposed to have one or more parameters? Why can't `onkeypress` be assigned a simple string type value instead of callback function `f`? Can you show me the W3C reference on this?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. `keypress` events are triggered when someone types on their keyboard, not when the click a mouse button.

Comment: Either I'm not understanding your question, or you're basically asking "*where do I find documentation on DOM UI events?*", which would be off-topic here.

Comment: @Bergi `onkeypress` is a keyboard event but not mouse event. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp function `getChar` is used by both keyboard and mouse events. function `f` is relevant to this question.

Comment: Read here http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html at par 1.4.:  `An object which implements the Event interface is generally passed as the first parameter to an event handler.`, thus, one single parameter, nothing else.

Comment: @overexchange: That's what I am saying. But your code talks about mouse button *clicks* (besides "key clicks", which is not a term). Btw, [don't use *schools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Bergi Is it an issue that `getChar` function receives both keyboard and mouse events. function `f` only receives keyboard events. function `f` is relevant to this question. I still did not get u

Comment: @overexchange: Yes, looks like an issue to me. The naming is confusing (there are no chars related to mouse events), and you should at least document it as such. Also in the context of this question it is only used for keyboard events. Btw, even `f` talks about "clicking" when meaning "pressing" or "typing".

Comment: @Bergi [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4p8y48xk/3/) is the working code. Query edited. Do you still see any issue?

Comment: @VincentDamiani What about `return` statement? Does event handler need to have `return` statement?